# How can I get all action (retweets and favorite) happened on a certain user tweets and who did this actions?

Tags: twitter

I am creating a competition for my twitter followers, so any one will retweet any of my tweets will gain 15 points and any one favorite any of my tweets will gain 10 points.

How can I use the APIs to get all action (retweets and favorite) happened on a certain user tweets and who did this actions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you want to use the make oAuth calls to the twitter API.  You want to start by getting the tweet details

[https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/show/%3Aid](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/show/%3aid)

That will return data about that tweet which will include how many times its between retweet or favourited.  Then you use the following to API calls to get details about retweets and favourites.

[https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/retweets/%3Aid](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/retweets/%3aid)

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/favorites/list